# How can I activate a specific window (but not all window) at specific app in Cocoa apps?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to create a OS X app which manages windows to switch them.

But I cannot find a appropriate solution to activate a **specific** window.

I found these way.

---

- Using AppleScript.

  - Specifing window by window title or window number.
  - However, if a window has same window title of other window, the activating is not working correctly.

---

```
-- For example, this script activate Google Chrome's second window
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
        set thewindow to window 2
        tell thewindow
            perform action "AXRaise"
        end tell
        set frontmost to true
    end tell
end tell
```

---

- Using `NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps`.

  - However, this way cannot specify a window.

---

```
NSRunningApplication* app = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier: PID];
[app activateWithOptions: NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps];
```

---

Does exist other appropricate way to activate specific window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessibility works fine for this. With AXRaiseWindow & switchToApp you can switch to any window.

Look at: https://github.com/jsuder/WindowFairy/blob/master/WindowManager.m

(Disclaimer: not my code and im not acquainted with the author. just using google)

note: There is also a CGWindowList API that can be used to enum windows but it is being deprecated. AX* stays though

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have searched kAXRaiseAction and AXUIElement, and then have succeeded in activating specific window.